# external featured image via URL now showing image WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, image

i am trying to show featured images from external URL by using featured imaged URL plugin in my WordPress site. but it is not showing the image. it shows that "src(unknown)" in image tag on front side. please help me out. you can check the page https://xcloziw.com/ (see on the top big thumbnail with 4 small thumnails )
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hotlinking images should be avoided, especially from that source.

*But to answer your question:*

Your site is HTTPS and the source is HTTP, if you take the time to look at your browser console you would see a mixed content error.

> Mixed Content:  The page at 'https://xcloziw.com/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
>   'http://i.***.co.uk/i/pix/2017/07/23/22/429EF23800000578-4723104-image-a-3_1500844111524.jpg'.
>
> **This content should also be served over HTTPS.**

Comment: p.s ill leave it to others to tell you a possible fix, I'm not willing to aid in property theft. ;p

Comment: can you please pm me the possible  solution please? its urgent thanks